# Can I git stash a merge in progress?

Tags: git, merge, git-stash

I'm in the middle of resolving conflicts for a git merge, but I want to get back to a clean state temporarily without losing the work I've already done on the merge. If I try to git stash, I get errors for each file for which a conflict has not yet been resolved: "needs merge".

Is there a good way to save the merge-in-progress? The only idea that I have is to clone the repo into a different folder, but that seems excessive.

Comment: If you clone the repository locally, it won't keep a separate copy of the repo history on disk, at least on Unix systems.  So if you have 10GB of history but 100MB of files, then you'll only use the extra 100MB.

Comment: The in-progress merge is stored in the index and work-tree.  Given that `git stash` makes two commits out of these two, you would think it would be just the right thing—except that the in-progress merge state cannot be stored in a commit: it contains metadata that git will not write into a tree.  The `stash` script could be modified to save the raw index file contents into a blob of its own, but this would get quite tricky.  I wouldn't want to attempt to code it up tonight. :-)  Re-cloning the repo seems like the best quick method.

Comment: clone's _made_ for this.

Answer (score 12):

You could use the `git worktree` command to add a new worktree in a different folder. This is like a 2nd index and worktree, but using the same git repo. `man git-worktree`:

```
   Manage multiple working trees attached to the same repository.

   A git repository can support multiple working trees, allowing you to check out
   more than one branch at a time. With git worktree add a new working tree is
   associated with the repository. This new working tree is called a "linked working
   tree" as opposed to the "main working tree" prepared by "git init" or "git clone".
   A repository has one main working tree (if it’s not a bare repository) and zero or
   more linked working trees.
```

Comment: [Usage example](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#_examples) in the git documentation.

Comment: Might be good to note that you would throw your *clean* branch into the new worktree, not the one you're working on right now.