# How to resume `git merge` after stashing the merge change

Tags: git

Let's assume I want to merge `branch_B` to `branch_A`. I did:

```
git checkout branch_A
git merge branch_B
```

This resulted into a wall of conflicts that took me quite a long time to fix. Then, I had to do something urgently on `branch_C`. I did:

```
git stash
git checkout branch_C
```

Now, I am done with the `branch_C` and want to continue with my merge. I did:

```
git checkout branch_A
git stash pop
```

However, the merge is now viewed as a simple diff between `branch_A` and my merge attempt. How do I unstash these changes as a merge being in progress?

Comment: There is a relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685407/can-i-git-stash-a-merge-in-progress). Clearly, a merge in progress can be stashed. But it doesn't say if I can resume merging.

Comment: Try merging again? If you can’t, as in you’re still merging, apply the stashed changes and run `git merge --continue`

Comment: An in-progress merge literally *can't* be stashed until all conflicts are resolved. Once they are resolved, `git stash` saves the resolutions, but destroys the in-progress merge; it probably should refuse to do the stash action. (I'd argue the fact that it lets you do this is a bit of a bug in Git.) A better plan for urgent side work is to use `git worktree add`. Of course it's too late for that here; but see jthill's answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply restart it and reload the stash results

```
git merge branch_B
git read-tree --reset -u stash
```

if you had work tree changes that weren't added, i.e. the stashed index state didn't match the stashed work tree, follow up with `git read-tree stash^2` to reload the index.